# A PromQL to calculate total network traffic received bytes over a timeframe

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, monitoring, promql, victoriametrics

I am trying to measure the amount of network traffic usage in my Kubernetes cluster and set limits for my containers based on their network usage. I am using Prometheus to collect metrics, and I need help with a PromQL query that can calculate the total network traffic received bytes over a specific time frame.

What would be the PromQL query to fetch the total network traffic received bytes over a specific time frame?

Comment: Are you using nginx ingress controller or some other ingress controller? Also, are you sure you want to calculate the received bytes (requests) instead of the sent bytes (responses)?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [increase](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#increase) function for metric which measures the amount of sent bytes. Specify the interval you want to measure on in square brackets. For example, `increase(network_bytes_sent_total[1h])` will return the increase of network_bytes_sent_total metric between now() and now()-1h.